# The KeyHolder returns "GENERATED_KEY" while executing select query on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mysql-connector

I'm developing the spring boot application with MySQL as well as Postgres. My tests are failing with the following error when I run with MySQL properties. But it's working fine on Postgres as well as H2. I'm using MySQL latest version,

```
implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.25'
```

My Create table definition,

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user");

jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (\n" +
         "  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
         "  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL\n" +
          ")");
```

I used the following code to insert a row,

```
            KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            String query = "insert into user (name) values ('Foo')";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query, new String[]{"PrimaryKeyColumnName"});
                return ps;

            }, keyHolder);

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : keyHolder.getKeys().entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("ENTRY: " + entry);
                List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM user WHERE " + entry.getKey() + "= ?", entry.getValue());
                System.out.println("result: " + result);
            }
```

MySQL properties,

```
# MySQL Config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
```

**Error:**

```
ENTRY: GENERATED_KEY=1
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM user WHERE GENERATED_KEY= ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'GENERATED_KEY' in 'where clause'
```

H2 properties,

```
# H2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When I use H2, which returns the primary key column name,

```
ENTRY: ID=1
```

What is missing in MySQL, how can I get the primary key column name instead of GENERATED_KEY on MySQL?

Any inputs here really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is an issue on the line below

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM user WHERE " + entry.getKey() + "= ?", entry.getValue());
```

`entry.getKey()` should be the `id` column, so the following line might work for you;

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Yes, but how should we populate on keyholder on MySQL. The above code is working fine on Postgres as well as H2.

Comment: Hi @SST,
Maybe,  I couldn't get what exactly you are trying to do. the auto-generated key becomes available to you when the row is inserted into the table. I mean when you do insert operation, the keyholder returns the primary key that is generated by MySql DB. So, the id value is already available in the table.

Comment: The auto-generated key return value is fine, but the primary key column is GENERATED_KEY instead of id

Comment: ahh ok, I got it now. Seems like MySql has never returned the correct column name for it :(

Comment: Is there any document for this?

Comment: I don't know, but KeyHolder stuff belongs to Spring, maybe there is a bug in the implementation of Spring. If you use low-level pure JDBC implementation, ResultSetMetadata may provide you the column name of the generated key.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Nigel!